# How can I get sorted value of date in combobox in vb?

Tags: vb.net, date

i am writing a simple application to collect the folder named as dates from a directory and add to combobox. i want to sort the list before it added to it ? 
  Any suggestion

```
Dim filepath As String = FileStr
Dim directoryPath As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath)
For Each file As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath)
 ComboBox1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file))
Next
```

Comment: You want to order it how?

Comment: DD-MM-YYYY   in this format

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ's `OrderBy` and `Date.TryParseExact`. I would also use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` instead since it doesn't need to read all files.

```
Dim formats = {"dd-MM-yyyy", "yyyyMMdd"}
Dim dt As DateTime
Dim orderedFiles = From file In System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath)
                   Let fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)
                   Where Date.TryParseExact(fileName, formats, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, dt)
                   Order By dt Ascending
                   Select fileName 
For Each fileName As String In orderedFiles
    ComboBox1.Items.Add( fileName )
Next
```

Comment: The output comes as usual .

Comment: @Satyajit: i cannot help with such little informations.

Comment: @Satyajit: I'm parsing it and then i'm using it in the `OrderBy`.

Comment: but  the output comes as previously

Comment: @Satyajit: you have neither shown sample files nor mentioned the allowed formats or what's wrong with your approach.

Comment: @Satyajit: bad sample, what is the day and what is the month? But if it adds items it means that the `Where`-filter of my LINQ query parsed file-names successfully. Otherwise your combobox would be empty. You can use `Descending` instead of `Ascending` to see the newest files first.